# Getting [Errno 13] Permission denied for non-blocking read

Tags: python, python-2.7, nonblocking

I am trying to implement simple non-blocking reading by using [python-nonblock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nonblock). I wrote the following code (Python 2.7, Mac OSX):

```
from nonblock import nonblock_read
import subprocess
import time


def goSleep():
    print('Sleeping for a while! ...!')
    time.sleep(20)


def processData(data):
    print('This is my data ...!')
    print(data)


def doSecondaryTask():
    for i in range(1000):
        print('Count: %s\n' % i)
        time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(['filetest.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        data = nonblock_read(pipe.stdout)
        if data is None:
            # All data has been processed and subprocess closed stream
            pipe.wait()
            break
        elif data:
            # Some data has been read
            processData(data)
        else:
            # No data is on buffer, but subprocess has not closed stream
            goSleep()

    # To prove that non-blocking read is working
    doSecondaryTask()
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "io.py", line 16, in <module>
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(['filetest.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I am not sure why I get `Permission denied`! I have googled few pages but still cannot see the problem. Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: `filetest.txt` is probably not an executable file.

Comment: @jasonharper Does it have to be an executable file? My goal is to read from a text file

Comment: Well, given that `subprocess.Popen()` has the specific purpose of running other programs, yes it does have to be executable!  You could use `['cat', 'filetest.txt']` as the command to execute - but normally, if you just want to read a text file, you'd use `open()` and read it directly, and this non-blocking module you're using would be of no benefit.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for enlightening me about that. I thought subprocess would fit my purpose of non-blocking reading file.